# I can't pass data between pages

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app and I need to use the data from an Entry Text in another page

I Created a class

```
public class Calculos
{
    public string puntos { get; set; }
    public decimal distancia { get; set; }
    public string personas { get; set; } 
    public string carros { get; set; }
    public string buses { get; set; }
    public int gaseosas { get; set; }
    public decimal monto { get; set; }
}
```

then i created the user entry text

```
public async void Siguiente_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Calculos calculos = new Calculos();

    calculos.personas = Personas.Text.ToString();
    calculos.carros = Carros.Text.ToString();
    calculos.buses = Buses.Text.ToString();

    MitadMundo myHomePage = new MitadMundo();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(myHomePage, true);
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(myHomePage);
}
```

And after all is the final view

```
public CarritoPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Calculos calculos = new Calculos();
    string calc = calculos.personas;
    Personas.Text = calc;

}
```

and this how it looks in XAML

```
<Label x:Name="Personas"  FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<Label x:Name="Carros"  FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
<Label x:Name="Buses"  FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

but the data is not showing anything when i test the app
i don't know if it is something in the entry text
or if it's something wrong with the final page
i would really appreciate your help

Comment: You create a new instance of the Calculos class. Instead, you need to pass the object you use before to the later view, so that it is used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not doing anything to actually pass data

try this

```
// pass the instance of calculos to the new page
MitadMundo myHomePage = new MitadMundo(calculos);
```

then, in that page's constructor

```
public MitadMundo(Calculos calc)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Personas.Text = calc.personas;
}
```

Comment: without seeing your actual code I can't tell you what's wrong.  Either update your question with the modified code, or break out the debugger and step through it to figure out whats wrong

Comment: it's working right now, thanks, the only think im a little bit worried is because i'ts not the inmediate next page, so i have to pass the data between all the pages, do you think it should be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

when you are using 'new' which means you are creating new instance of that class. new instance wouldnt have any values previously you set anywhere else.

`Calculos calculos = new Calculos();`

what you have to do is pass the calculos object to wherver you going to read the values.
`Calculos calculos = new Calculos();
calculos.personas = Personas.Text.ToString();
calculos.carros = Carros.Text.ToString();
calculos.buses = Buses.Text.ToString();`

pass this calculos object to any class or page where you want to read values from.